# How can I determine what finalizers are being called?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Since a finalizer being called usually indicates a missing Dispose() call, I would like determine what finalizers are being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what could be the right answer. But profilers/perfromance counters can help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

How about:-

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType());
```

Comment: That is good for my classes.  I would like that ability for framework classes also.

Comment: Tricky, if you could examine what is passing through the freachable queue that might give you a clue but I wouldn't know how to do that.  I agree with shahkalpesh, a profiler could highlight where something disposable isn't being disposed.